# Is every finite subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$ is a zero set of a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to do the following exercise:

> Is any finite subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$ the zero set of a polynomial $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$? Prove or find a counterexample.

Here I interpreted the "any" to mean "every". Then my thought was that this is indeed true since suppose the finite subset is given by
$$A= \{(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),...\}$$

Then take the polynomial

$$P(x,y)= ((x-a)+(y-b))((x-c)+(y-d))((x-e)+(y-f))...$$

Then the zero set of this polynomial would the set $A$ right? Is my solution correct or am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: Really looks fine. It's my interpretation as well.

Comment: The polynomial might have *more* zeros than the set $A$. It says "Is there any finite set, which is *the* zero set", so equal to it. The answer is negative, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25556/why-are-there-no-discrete-zero-sets-of-a-polynomial-in-two-complex-variables).

Comment: Dietrich Burde’s comment is right: any $(a-\lambda,b+\lambda)$ will be a zero of the polynomial.

Comment: In fact _no_ finite set is the zero set of a bivariate polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "Is any finite subset of C2 the zero set of a polynomial C[x,y]? Prove or find a counterexample."

**Answer:** If $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]:=A$ with $B:=A/(f), V(f):=Spec(B)$, and $f$ is a non-constant polynomial, it follows $dim(Spec(B))=1$. Hence $Spec(B)$ cannot be a finite set of points: A finite set of points is a set of dimension $0$.