# When is the zero set of a polynomial in two complex variables disconnected?

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

For background, I'm just starting to learn a little bit about classical algebraic geometry, so I'm trying to look at some simple problems that are as concrete as possible to develop an intuition.

This question is [similar to this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25556), but I'm interested in when I get multiple disconnected segments in the solution set as opposed to whether the solution set is discrete or not.

Let $p(x, y)$ be a polynomial in at most $\{x, y\}$ with a zero constant term. $0$ is a valid value for $p(x, y)$, as is $x^2$, $y^3$ and $xy+4x^2y^7$. $4$ is not a valid value for $p(x, y)$. I'm looking at sets of the form $\{ (x, y) : p(x, y) = c \}$.

Suppose $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$. I'll say $X$ is *path-connected* if and only if, for every pair points $(p, q)$, there exists a continuous function $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{C}^2$ such that $f(0) = p$ and $f(1) = q$ and $f([0, 1]) \subset X$. Using a result [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness), a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is connected if and only if it is path connected, so I'll just say that $X$ is connected for simplicity.

The solution set of $x^2 = 1$ is the union of $\{ (1, y) : y \in \mathbb{C}\}$ and $\{(-1, y) : y \in \mathbb{C}\}$. This set is not connected.

It seems pretty clear that when $p(x, y)$ is of the form $x^n$ or $y^n$ for $n \ge 2$ and $c \neq 0$, we get a disconnected set. So these conditions are sufficient.

However, I'm wondering what conditions are *necessary and sufficient*.